# How can I get the meta-data information of a pushButton in Qt? 

Tags: qt

When I read some passage about Qt's Signals & Slots , they talk about metadata just as follow. How can I get it?

```
static const uint qt_meta_data_QPushButton[] = {

 // content:
       1,       // revision
       0,       // classname
       0,    0, // classinfo
       2,   10, // methods
       3,   20, // properties
       0,    0, // enums/sets

 // slots: signature, parameters, type, tag, flags
      13,   12,   12,   12, 0x0a,
      24,   12,   12,   12, 0x08,

 // properties: name, type, flags
      44,   39, 0x01095103,
      56,   39, 0x01095103,
      64,   39, 0x01095103,

       0        // eod
};

static const char qt_meta_stringdata_QPushButton[] = {
    "QPushButton/0/0showMenu()/0popupPressed()/0bool/0autoDefault/0default/0"
    "flat/0"
};

const QMetaObject QPushButton::staticMetaObject = {
    { &QAbstractButton::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_QPushButton,
      qt_meta_data_QPushButton, 0 }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you pasted is the output from the Qt MOC tool. You will find it under "Generated Files" in your Qt project. Since it's generated you are not supposed to modify it directly.

MOC is Qt's Meta-Object Compiler which is documented [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html). It is located in the *bin* directory of your Qt installation (probably *C:\Qt\4.6.2\bin\moc.exe*).

To use it just run:

```
moc.exe -o <output_file> <input_file>
```

And the tool will generate the MOC'd header file which contains the metadata that you are after.

Comment: thanks for your answer at first.  But in my project files there are 'xx.o' and 'xx.exe' , no this file . Can you give me more information about it?

Comment: I've updated the answer with MOC example usage. I hope this answers your question.